# Pandas 'on_bad_lines' param unexpected default behavior

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Pandas on_bad_line is not cooperating as I would expect from the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Consider the following:

```
data = b'Name,Address,Company\nMike,"1234RdCity, State",Acme,LLC'
pd.read_csv(BytesIO(data))
```

I would think that this would error, because the first record has more unescaped, unquoted delimiters than the headers (default parameter values are header=0, on_bad_line = 'error'), but instead it creates a dataframe like:

|  | Name | Address | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 1234RdCity, State | Acme | LLC |

How can I make pandas throw an exception when it discovers a 'bad line', which as I understand it is defined as a line with more delimiters than the header row?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is that you can specify you don't want to read index column (you don't have any index in your CSV). Then pandas will print warning.
You can then switch this warning to regular exception:

```py
import warnings
from io import BytesIO

import pandas as pd

warnings.filterwarnings("error")

data = b'Name,Address,Company\nMike,"1234RdCity, State",Acme,LLC'

try:
    df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(data), index_col=False)
    print(df)
except pd.errors.ParserWarning:
    print("Bad line")
```

Prints:

```
Bad line
```

Comment: Two follow up questions then: Is the default behavior that if there exactly *one* extra delimiter then by default pandas assumes the first column is the index -  and where is that documented? And secondly, the docs say that the default value for on_bad_lines is "error", why then is it warning instead? Furthermore, why doesn't overriding the default with on_bad_lines = 'error' throw an exception?